# too much gap between cardviews in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a **RecyclerView** inside a **RelativeLayout** like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/cards_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="#eeff99"/>
```

and I have card view within a **LinearLayout** like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/quote_card"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#666"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/display_author_name"
        android:text="Author Name"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

the gap between the cards are huge. The next card is seen only after one scroll a bit. What am I missing?

Here the images, before scrolling:

[image: before scrolling]

After scrolling:

[image: after scrolling]

Comment: Also show your LinearLayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
      xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/quote_card"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#666"
      card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
      card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
      app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/display_author_name"
          android:text="Author Name"
          android:textSize="18sp"
          android:textColor="#333"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

put card view in side a linear layout and make play with padding to change the gap

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
*android:padding="1dp"*

>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    style="@style/list_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes in your `LinearLayout`. If `layout_height` is `match_parent` it takes the screens space

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score -1):

you used card view height as match parent so if parent height also match parent than change parent height into  wrap content and if you used only card view as parent than also change its height  to wrap content..might be it help you